# Would this infinite product converge?

Tags: calculus

I'm just curious if this would work.  The first [products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278486/what-is-this-product) I looked at are trivial.  I just want to know if more can be said about this one:

$$f(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+\large\frac{(-1)^n}{nx}}$$

Does this now converge?

Comment: Please try it yourself. What do you thing SE is? A place where you can freely give other people questions that you have not thought about? Please dont.

Comment: It's a valuable learning experience.  I'm not afraid to ask stupid questions.

Comment: Its not about bad questions. Please keep in mind other people take their own time to answer this. Maybe put some thought into it yourself.

Comment: The most important thing is to never stop asking questions.  I don't understand why you sir are telling me to do the exact opposite!

Comment: I think what CBenni is saying is that you should tell us what you tried. Do you know any criterion for a product to converge? Have you tried to apply it? What difficulties did you encounter? Etc.

Comment: Your question is not "stupid", but your attitude is. The purpose of MSE is to provide guide to users who *already* tried something to get the answer. Is good to never stop asking questions, but please, first ask *to yourself*.

Comment: Checked the "faqs" and "about".  And what you're saying about the purpose of MSE is false.  I think the question is answerable and I am curious about any explanation.  Enough said.  Anyway, I tried looking for a bound $\prod(1+a_n)$ because then convergence of $\sum a_n$ would imply convergence.

Comment: @user54358 OK, now please share with us your thoughts about the convergence of the series $\sum a_n$, feel free to edit your original post to include this.

Answer (score 1):

So I just looked at convergence of the reciprocal.

$g(x)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{nx}\right)$

Convergence of $g$ is [equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243594/infinite-product-is-converges?rq=1) to convergence of the sum

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{nx} = -\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} = -\frac{ln2}{x}$

The last sum is the [alternating harmonic series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Alternating_harmonic_series) Ok I don't know if this is correct.  Because the sum is not defined for $x=0$ but the original product is undefined for $x=\frac{1}{n}$ where $n$ is odd.